# form submit redirecting to index page of codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When clicking my submit button of the form the page is redirecting to the index page i.e the welcome message of codigniter. but the url shows the requested page. . I m confused.

view page:

```
<form action='welcome/register' method='post'>
<table>......
......
</form>
```

and in controller page i ve done the validation and if validation fails it have to redirect to register_new page but the redirected page is the welcome page of codeignitor. . But no problem with the url.

Comment: Could you please add some code? Mind reading is not my specialty

Comment: url shows the requested page. that means form action is set correct. Check the requested page code.

Comment: have u tried using `site_url()` in your forms action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you use forms in CodeIgniter. Don't try to use HTML forms like that, just use CodeIgniter style

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Add this to your controller (to load the form helper):

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

In your view

```
<?php echo form_open('controllername/functionname');?>
     <input type ...>
     //...more inputs
</form>
```

It redirects to the original page if action is not specified. It shouldn't redirect to the index page ever unless specified by second controller.